# Styling a inline added background image

Tags: css, background-image, inline-styles

how I can add style to an image added via inline css. there are several other images so I cant use the img tag in the CSS, I dont have access to the CSS of the page.

I want to fit the image into the div.

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3" style="
    background-image: url('https://...png);
>
...
</div>
```

Comment: do you need to style to an image or to target the element who contains the inline background image?

Comment: just the background image

Comment: could you clarify how this image should be styled? what's the expected result?

Comment: I want to fit the image into the div

Comment: _“I want to fit the image into the div”_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

Was that what you wanted? i can change the background-image with css file.

```css
.aclass {
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/400/320') !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3 aclass" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/400/300')">

</div>
```